# Controlled gain connecting input voltages to opamp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, adc

Suppose we have a charged capacitor and at time t=0 we close the switch and the capacitor starts discharging.

[image]

Is there a circuit with an opamp which amplifies it with a controlled gain? I don't want the 100k+ amplification if we just connect the 2 ends of the resistor to the inverting and non inverting pin because I want to translate the voltage difference  to digital values. Help appreciated.

Comment: Useful search term : negative feedback.

Comment: You think I haven't searched that? The lower voltage of the opamp is 0 so any negative feedback won't help me much

Comment: Then you have some learning to do, about how to use NFB in basic opamp circuits.

Comment: A non-inverting op-amp with gain looks like it will work.

Comment: Ah OK I get it what you mean but the capacitor can also be charging it is a part of a larger circuit.

Comment: Evolving requirements are fun!  If the cap can be charging and discharging, then forget about the cap and focus on measuring bi-directional current through the resistor.